# How would you catch the error

Tags: angular, error-handling, catch-block

How would you catch the error in that case:

```
   getStuff(): Observable<Stuff[]> {

    return this.http.get(url)
      .map((res: Response) => {
        return res.json()
        .map(item => {
          return {
            id: item.id
            name: item.code
          };
      });
    });

  }
```

I tried to put `.catch()` but saying that return type is not matching `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

```
getStuff(): Observable<Stuff[]> {

    return this.http.get(url)
      .map((res: Response) => {
        return res.json()
        .map(item => {
          return {
            id: item.id
            name: item.code
          };
      });
    })
    .catch();

  }
```

with `.catch((err) => console.error(err));` getting 
`Argument of type '(err: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<any>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.`

Comment: try `.catch((err) => console.error(err));`

Comment: @Jerry06 with this one `Argument of type '(err: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<any>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'`

Comment: The `.catch()` as in `Observable.catch()` is only valid after the initial `.map()`. So `.get().map().catch()` in the observable chain. Yours is in the wrong place.

Comment: @NeilLunn I do not think so that it is in the wrong place, it is exactly in the chain `.get().map().catch()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use with `Observable.throw`

```
function handleError(error: any) {

  let errorMsg = error.message || `Yikes! There was was a problem `;
  console.error(errorMsg);

  // throw an application level error
  return Observable.throw(errorMsg);
}
```

And using

```
 .catch(handleError);
```

Comment: this working, but how would you do something like `.catch(throw new MyError())` instead of declaring any additional functions?

Comment: try `.catch(errorMsg => Observable.throw(errorMsg))`